# How to generate a unique single random number each time in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, random

I know there are some similar questions,but all of them just return a list,I just need a number,each time random generate a unique single number:

Now I'm using Python to build a loop:

```
for _ in range(9):
        random_number=random.randint(1,11)
        print(random_number)
```

My question is how to make sure each time the **random_number** is unique,not repeating in all 9 times.
I don't need a list,just the random_number

Comment: Check if the number has been used already and roll the random number again if it's not unique.

Comment: Generate a list of sequential numbers, shuffle it, then simply iterate it from start to end.

Comment: @PM77-1, post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @Jim - I wanted to provide a guidance - not an answer.

Comment: It sounds like you may have found ways to do this, the insight may be to loop over the list of numbers, rather than trying to generate a new value independently each iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `random.sample` over the target range of numbers to pick a desired number of unique numbers from them:

```
import random
for random_number in random.sample(range(1, 12), 9):
    print(random_number)
```

Comment: oo, TIL this exists!

Comment: Thank you,this is what I want!

Answer (score 4):

If you want each number to be unique from all the others, you don't want a truly random number each time (it's in fact very improbable for random numbers within a small set to be unique).  I'd do it like this:

```
numbers = list(range(1, 12))
random.shuffle(numbers)
for random_number in numbers[:9]:
    print(random_number)
```

Essentially it's like taking a deck of cards, shuffling it, and then dealing the top nine cards.  You'll get nine "random" cards but they will never repeat since they're coming from the same deck and you aren't reshuffling in between deals (consequently they aren't truly random, which is why card-counting is a thing).

Comment: If anyone wants to investigate Sam's parenthetical comment there, look up the "Birthday Paradox".

Answer (score 2):

`random.sample` is definitely the way to go, but another idea is to initialize all numbers in a list and then randomly pop one at a time:

```
import random

numbers = list(range(1, 12))
for _ in range(9):
    random_index = random.randint(0, len(numbers)-1)
    selected_rn = numbers.pop(random_index)
```

This has a nice interpretation: a predefined sequence of numbers that you point to a number of times and grab one number at random.